# Trying to switch left/right alignment of two views repeatedly in my Android app

Tags: android

This is the code in my Adapter file to change the alignment of the views dynamically, when I run the app, the first part shows correctly, but the else statement when encountered it does not show the TextView. Where am I going wrong?

```
private void setAlignment(ViewHolder holder, boolean isMe) {
    if (!isMe) {
        holder.chatIcon.setImageResource(R.drawable.dpf_p);
        holder.contentWithBG.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.me);
        holder.txtMessage.setTextColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.lightRed));


        // this is the layout alignment part

        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) holder.content.getLayoutParams();
        lp.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT);
        holder.content.setLayoutParams(lp);

        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lpicon = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) holder.icon.getLayoutParams();
        lpicon.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT);
        holder.icon.setLayoutParams(lpicon);

        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lpbg = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) holder.contentWithBG.getLayoutParams();
        lpbg.addRule(RelativeLayout.LEFT_OF, holder.icon.getId());
        holder.contentWithBG.setLayoutParams(lpbg);

        LinearLayout.LayoutParams lpLicon= (LinearLayout.LayoutParams) holder.chatIcon.getLayoutParams();
        holder.chatIcon.setLayoutParams(lpLicon);

        LinearLayout.LayoutParams lpLms= (LinearLayout.LayoutParams) holder.txtMessage.getLayoutParams();
        holder.txtMessage.setLayoutParams(lpLms);

    } else {
        holder.chatIcon.setImageResource(R.drawable.l);
        holder.contentWithBG.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.k);
        holder.txtMessage.setTextColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.darkGray));


        // this is the layout alignment part

        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) holder.content.getLayoutParams();
        lp.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_LEFT);
        holder.content.setLayoutParams(lp);

        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lpicon = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) holder.icon.getLayoutParams();
        lpicon.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_LEFT);
        holder.icon.setLayoutParams(lpicon);

        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lpbg = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) holder.contentWithBG.getLayoutParams();
        lpbg.addRule(RelativeLayout.RIGHT_OF, holder.icon.getId());
        holder.contentWithBG.setLayoutParams(lpbg);

        LinearLayout.LayoutParams lpLicon= (LinearLayout.LayoutParams) holder.chatIcon.getLayoutParams();
        holder.chatIcon.setLayoutParams(lpLicon);

        LinearLayout.LayoutParams lpLms= (LinearLayout.LayoutParams) holder.txtMessage.getLayoutParams();
        holder.txtMessage.setLayoutParams(lpLms);
    }
}
```

This is the xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/icon"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="50sp"
        android:layout_height="50sp"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/chatIcon"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_logo"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/contentWithBackground"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/img_in"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtMessage"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:maxWidth="240dp"
            android:textSize="18sp"/>

    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Post your xml file code for better understanding or Better to use two layout xml files for left and right..

Comment: Its a lot of work, plus its not elegant, when I just need to switch sides of two views, which should be achieved by adding the addRules method

Answer (score 0):

Just found out a way out of the problem, I removed the rules that were opposing to the rules I tried setting each time.

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lpicon = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) holder.icon.getLayoutParams();
        lpicon.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT, 0);
        holder.icon.setLayoutParams(lpicon);

        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lpicon_ = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) holder.icon.getLayoutParams();
        lpicon_.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_LEFT);
        holder.icon.setLayoutParams(lpicon_);
```

now its working.Thanks!